# How to replace character between two characters?

Tags: java, regex

I have strings "ABC DE", "ABC FE", "ABC RE".

How to replace the characters between ABC and E using regex?

Trying to do this with a regex and replace

```
str.replace((ABC )[^*](E), 'G');
```

Comment: What result are you wanting, `ABC GE`?

Comment: Why not just set the strings equal to "ABC GE"?

Comment: If so... `str.replaceAll("(ABC )[^*](E)", "$1G$2");`

Comment: The question makes no sense. Please specify what you exactly want to do, and why. What are the Strings? Do you only have 3 Strings that are constantly "ABC DE", "ABC FE", "ABC RE"? What is the result you are expecting? Is it constantly "ABC GE"? If so `str = "ABC GE"` is the simplest solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove any characters that appear between "ABC " and "E", then you could accomplish this via lookaheads and the [`replaceAll()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm) method :

```
String[] strings = { "ABC DE", "ABC FE", "ABC RE" };
for(int s = 0; s < strings.length; s++){
    // Update each string, replacing these characters with a G
    strings[s] = strings[s].replaceAll("(?<=ABC ).*(?=E)","G"));
}
```

Likewise if you didn't explicitly want the space after "ABC", simply remove it from the lookahead by using `(?<=ABC).*(?=E)`.

You can [see an interactive example of this here](https://ideone.com/r4LsFP).

Comment: Does not work, replace with empty string when the OP wants G.

Comment: @Tunaki I didn't realize it was a G. I've updated accordingly, however the same basic idea still holds.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to use regex `replaceAll` with `"ABC(.*?)E"` instead.

```
str = str.replaceAll("ABC(.*?)E", "G");
```

Explanation:

```
ABC matches the characters ABC literally (case sensitive)
1st Capturing group (.*?)
.*? matches any character (except newline)
Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
E matches the character E literally (case sensitive)
```

Comment: What about `str = "ABC GE"`?!

Comment: It is replaced to itself, no?

Comment: No I mean, instead of `str = str.replaceAll("ABC(.*?)E", "G");`, you can just have `str = "ABC GE"` since the result is always going to be that. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @SystemMGR ah yes. Anyway, Tunaki seems to suggest you to put more elaborate examples to make the point of the question clearer

Comment: @Tunaki in the given example by the OP, yes, since the replacement is just "G". But likely it is just minimal demonstration of what he wants (I might be wrong, though)

Comment: I don't understand the question then. What's the point of it all?

Comment: @Tunaki minimal example? well, yes, typically you want to replace by group though...